# Json not deserelizing properly

Tags: json, serialization, gson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I need to connect to a certain API, so i am using their API documentation to generate the API calling client and models so i can use their API. However, one of their calls seems to be giving me an error. When calling that certain API endpoint, **the response looks like this**:

```
 {
      "Data": {
        "Account": [
          {
            "AccountId": "111001",
            "Currency": "GBP",
            "AccountType": "Personal",
            "AccountSubType": "CurrentAccount",
            "Nickname": "Bills",
            "Account": {
              "SchemeName": "UK.OBIE.SortCodeAccountNumber",
              "Identification": "80200110203345",
              "Name": "Mr Kevin",
              "SecondaryIdentification": "00021"
            }
          },
          {
            "AccountId": "111002",
            "Currency": "GBP",
            "AccountType": "Personal",
            "AccountSubType": "CurrentAccount",
            "Nickname": "Household",
            "Account": {
              "SchemeName": "UK.OBIE.SortCodeAccountNumber",
              "Identification": "80200110203348",
              "Name": "Mr Kevin"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "Links": {
        "Self": "https://blablabla.com"
      },
      "Meta": {
        "TotalPages": 1
      }
    }
```

**The models used to deserilize this response are** :

```
public class AccountResponseDtoClassUsedToDeserilizeProperly {
        @JsonProperty("Data")
        private Data data;
        @JsonProperty("Links")
        private Links links;
        @JsonProperty("Meta")
        private Meta meta;
    }
```

---

```
 public class Data {
        @JsonProperty("Account")
        private List<Account> account = null;
}
```

---

```
 public class Account {



@JsonProperty("AccountId")
    private String accountId;
    @JsonProperty("Currency")
    private String currency;
    @JsonProperty("AccountType")
    private String accountType;
    @JsonProperty("AccountSubType")
    private String accountSubType;
    @JsonProperty("Nickname")
    private String nickname;
    @JsonProperty("Account")
    private Account_ account;
}
```

---

```
public class Account_ {
   @JsonProperty("SchemeName")
        private String schemeName;
        @JsonProperty("Identification")
        private String identification;
        @JsonProperty("Name")
        private String name;
        @JsonProperty("SecondaryIdentification")
        private String secondaryIdentification;
    }
```

**Some unimportant models have been left out.**

When trying to deserilize, this is the error i recieve:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 149 path $.Data.Account[0].Account
```

**My suspicion for the problem is:**
In model `Data` there is an attribue names Account that is a list.

In model `Account` there is an attribute named Account that is an object. Could the deserilizer get confused because of this?

- So how can i fix this? Any solution would be great, but keep in mind that all of these models are generated code from a yaml file, so the best solution would be something that would not interfere with the models, since they will get regenerated on the next build. Thank you!

Comment: How do you deserialize the json? Do you ues `gson.fromJson(json, AccountResponseDtoClassUsedToDeserilizeProperly.class);`´or something else?

Comment: Yes, i get the error mentioned above using `AccountResponseDtoClassUsedToDeserilizeProperly example = new Gson().fromJson(json, AccountResponseDtoClassUsedToDeserilizeProperly.class);`. I also tried doing this: `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                            AccountResponseDtoClassUsedToDeserilizeProperly accountsResponse = mapper.readValue(json, AccountResponseDtoClassUsedToDeserilizeProperly.class);`. Doing that i get an object where everything is mapped to the Data attribute.

Comment: I tried your code and I don't get the mentioned error for the given string. Something that strikes me as odd is that you are using `gson` but you have jackson annotations - `@JsonProperty`. Is this intended?

Comment: @Fred did you deserilize it using the models provided ? I fixed this issue in a cheap way by creating another model that does not cause the issue. As for the GSON and Jackson stuff, yes it is indented here, as this is only a sample code.

Comment: I used your models and the line you have in the comments - `new Gson().fromJson(json, AccountResponseDtoClassUsedToDeserilizeProperly.class)`. U do get Al the fields null because they have different names than the json, but the deserialization doesn't crash.

Comment: Also according to your models, the exception doesn't make sense because at the level it mentions you have an object and not an array. The exception says it was expecting an array...